# Application has stopped unexpectedly with Force close?

Tags: android, exception

When I am running a program in android 2.1. I got an error **Application has stopped unexpectedly** then force close.I clean the project again and again then build but the issue still remains.This program need to display the **Email Address** of all the contacts from the emulator on the ListView.

**code**

```
public class Trial3 extends Activity {

ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listview);  
   btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
   itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
   lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           GetEmails();
           Toast.makeText(Trial3.this, "working...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }); 
}

private void GetEmails()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        {               
            emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            contactlist.add(emailAddress);
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        emails.close();

    }
    cursor.close(); 
}
}
```

**Logcat**

```
 06-14 15:03:17.339: D/AndroidRuntime(502): Shutting down VM
 06-14 15:03:17.339: W/dalvikvm(502): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
 06-14 15:03:17.339: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=502, uid=10028 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQuery(ContentProviderNative.java:326)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:345)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:202)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at com.abhi.Trial3.GetEmails(Trial3.java:45)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at com.abhi.Trial3.access$0(Trial3.java:42)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at com.abhi.Trial3$1.onClick(Trial3.java:36)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
 06-14 15:03:17.349: E/AndroidRuntime(502):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a permission to read contacts data to your application manifest as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

missing permission

```
49: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts from pid=502, uid=10028 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

add in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the android permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

on AndroidManifest.xml file  before the `<manifest>`.

Answer (score 0):

add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

& check the following
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CONTACTS